# Simple product images in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, cart

I've already enabled the "**Product thumbnail itself**" setting inside the configuration page, but the images inside my simple products are still being overridden by the configurable product.

I'm taking a look in 
`\template\1.9.1.x\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml` and I see that on line 20 it has this

```
echo '<img '. $_item->getProduct()->getProductMediaResized(480, 'thumbnail')
```

I've tried changing it to `small_images`, `images`, along with different sizes but the only thing it's caching is the main configurable product picture.

The only extension that I have installed that could have any affect on this may be One page checkout but I've yet to see how...

So basically I want the simple product thumbnail to be displayed inside the cart. It does work when I'm adding it into the cart (the popup) but within the cart itself its only displaying the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found out how to fix it.

I replaced the entire block:

```
        <?php 
            $escaped_label = $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getProductName());
            echo '<img '. $_item->getProduct()->getProductMediaResized(480, 'thumbnail')
                ->addImageHtmlAttributte('alt', $escaped_label)
                ->addImageHtmlAttributte('title', $escaped_label)
                ->getImageHtmlAttributte().' />';

        ?>
```

with

```
   <?php 
        $escaped_label = $this->escapeHtml($_item->getProduct()->getProductName()); 
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" />
```